# flutter desktop application "error MSB3073: The command "setlocal "

Tags: visual-c++, flutter-dependencies, visual-studio-2022, powershell-cmdlet, flutter-desktop

I was building a flutter desktop app using vs code and all sudden was presented with this error completely unfamiliar with.

[image: error]

anyone with a solution on how to handle this, I appreciate

following is my flutter doctor log:
[image]

Comment: Can you add **flutter doctor** log.

Comment: added the flutter doctor log

Answer (score 11):

Open visual studio installer, click on **modify**, then open **Individual components**.

Select latest **Windows 10 SDK** version and install it.

When SDK successfully installed

- open Android studio.
- flutter clean.
- flutter run.

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I had the same problem, I upgraded to Windows 10 latest SDK (in my case 10.0.20348.0)
clean the cache and run using those CLI's:

- flutter clean
- flutter run

Work great :-)